# Out of core resampling

Tags: image-processing, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, bigdata

I have a large image file (single band) that do not fit in my ram.
I wan to read it as numpy array (data) and plot it using matplotlib, possibly using `imshow(data)`. I know how to do it for a small-sized image. But how can I do it for large file? Ofcourse, its okay to resample (possibly scipy zoom) it before plotting. But how can I resample it before reading as numpy arrray because reading of large file into memory is not possible.

Comment: What format is your image ... is it a CSV of greyscale values with one image line per csv line?

Comment: @maxymoo it's geotiff

Comment: @Borys Depending on how you load the image you could try a memory mapped file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html (or the numpy equivalent: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

Comment: @kazemakase Sounds intersting! I'm reading image file using `imread`. But could not imagine how to apply memmap? Could you show some codes for it?

Comment: @Borys I have not used memory mapped files in Python myself. I just thought it might be useful for you :) The documentation says that `mmap` behaves like a file object, and the `imread` help says that you can pass it a file object. I guess it might be possible to construct a mmap object with your filename, and pass this object to imread. Cannot help you beyond that point, sorry...

Comment: @Borys numpy's `memmap` will probably not be useful for you. It expects the file to contain data that can be interpreted as a numpy array, which is usually not the case with image files. Maybe `mmap` could be useful for you instead (see above comment).

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is better to display the tiff with an external viewer https://superuser.com/questions/254677/what-software-works-well-for-viewing-massive-tiff-images-on-windows-7 .

Otherwise you could try to convert the tiff in an HDF5 file first (ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.org/HDF/contrib/salem/tiffutils.c) , and then load only a part of the matrix you want to display.